# In a Gitlab pipeline, if a python module is installed, why do I get a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import it?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a python script as part of a Gitlab pipeline.
It seems to start out ok and I can interact with python to get the version and have checked the system paths.
However, when I pip(3) install something from my gitlab-ci.yml I cannot then import it in the python script I call in the next line.

For example:

```
test:
 script:
  - pip3 install mysql <-- this gives no errors and reports success
  - python3 -c "import mysql" <-- this fails with ModuleNotFoundError...
```

The import statement also fails in my runtest.py script if I try to execute that from the pipeline with

```
 - python3 runtest.py
```

Here is my current gitlab-ci file:

```
stages:
 - test

image: python:latest

variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python3 -V
  - pip3 install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate

test:
 script:
  - pip3 install mysql
  - python3 -c "import mysql"
  - python3 runtest.py
 when: manual
```

What am I missing?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing mysql itself is not enough.

Python would need [mysql-connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) as well, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162970/6309).

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Then see if the same `ModuleNotFoundError` still pops up.